# Checking is time in specific time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, time

I want make a decision with `CASE Statement` on `time` format. But can't make a right decision with `time` formats because my end time of time range is smaller than start time. Let me explain with code;

```
DECLARE @Startdate datetime
DECLARE @START_TIME time(0)
DECLARE @END_TIME time(0)

SET @Startdate='2020-04-15 16:00:00.000'
SET @START_TIME='15:30:00'
SET @END_TIME='01:29:59'

select 
CASE WHEN CAST(@Startdate as time(0)) between @START_TIME and @END_TIME  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Also i have table in DB just like below;

```
ID  START_TIME  END_TIME
1   05:30:00    15:29:59
2   15:30:00    01:29:59
```

Just i want to check time of coming `datetime` value exactly fit with which `ID`. I don't care date part. How can i achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select case 
    when 
        (
            @end_time >= @start_time 
            and cast(@startdate as time(0)) >= @start_time 
            and cast(@startdate as time(0)) <= @end_time  
        )
        or (
            @end_time < @start_time 
            and (
                   cast(@startdate as time(0)) >= @start_time 
                or cast(@startdate as time(0)) <= @end_time
            )
        )           
    then 1 
    else 0 
end
```

Comment: `@Startdate='2020-04-15 13:00:00.000'` and  `@Startdate='2020-04-15 16:00:00.000'` both times return 1. But 13:00:00 should return 0.

Comment: @Lacrymae: ah, yes, that's correct. I modified the query a little, it seems to produce the correct results now.